# Cannot select the 2nd element with the same class Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am practising web scraping by making a bot that is supposed to go onto instagram and look at a persons following and mark down the names, i am able to get the first name by doing this

```js
  const follower = await page.$$eval(
    "div[class=' _ab8y  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p _abcm']",
    (el) => el.textContent
  );
  console.log(follower);
```

but i cant seem to find a way to find the next follower, as they both have the same class and no unique ID

I tried to do this

```
  const followerlist = []
  for (i=0; i < 10; i++){
    const follower = await page.$$eval(
      "div[class=' _ab8y  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p _abcm']",
      (el) => followerlist.push(el.textContent)
    );
  console.log(followerlist);
```

but it just gave me an array of 11 undefined objects

Comment: Doesn't `$$eval` already return an array?

Comment: I don't see how your first code block could do what you say it does. `$$eval` returns an array, and arrays don't have a `.textContent` property. Please examine this block again and [edit] the post to show what it actually is. It's probably `$eval`. As for your second block, `followerlist` doesn't exist in the browser where the callback runs. It's in Node, running in a totally different program on the computer. I can't remember if the `$$eval` would crash, but having an array of 11 empty objects also seems impossible. It'd be empty or crash.

Comment: In any case, you can't return DOM nodes from the browser. The normal syntax is `page.$$eval("your selector", els => els.map(e => e.textContent))`. If that doesn't work, please share a [mcve] with the page or relevant markup. Thanks. `for (i=0` creates a global variable. Always use `let` to scope the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your code examples work as you claim.

`page.$eval` selects the first matching element with `document.querySelector()`, then runs the callback on the element in the browser context.

`page.$$eval` selects all matching elements with `[...document.querySelectorAll()]` then runs the callback on the array of elements in the browser context.

For the first snippet, `el` is actually an array of zero or more elements since you used `$$eval`. Arrays don't have a `.textContent` property. It will return `undefined` from the browser context and assign it to `follower`.

Assuming the selector is correct and the element exists, replacing `$$eval` with `$$eval` should fix this first code block. Since that's what you claim you received, I suspect something was lost in translation to the question and you actually were using `$eval`.

---

The second code block will crash rather than return an array of empty objects. The reason it crashes is because `followerlist` isn't defined in the browser or passed into the browser from Node. It's a [common mistake](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#trying-to-access-variables-from-an-evaluate-callback) to assume all of the code runs in the same process and shares variables. In fact, the callback is serialized and runs in a totally different process.

You also [can't return DOM nodes from the browser back to Puppeteer](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#attempting-to-return-objects-and-dom-elements-from-evaluate-callbacks) without using `ElementHandles`.

Finally, `for (i=0;` inadvertently introduces a global variable, ripe for bugs. Always use `for (let i = 0;` to scope `i` to the `for` block.

But you don't need a loop here anyway. The correct pattern, again assuming the selector is correct, is:

```js
const results = await page.$$eval(
  "div[class=' _ab8y  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p _abcm']", // not good, discussed below
  els => els.map(e => e.textContent)
);
```

---

As indicated above, almost always avoid hyper-rigid selectors like the one you're using here. If the order of two classes changes or an extra space shows up, it'll fail. I can't see your markup, but almost certainly, you'll be safer using something like

```css
div._ab8y._ab94._ab97._ab9f._ab9k._ab9p._abcm
```

Although there [might be a better way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) than this, at least the ordering of the classes, presence of extra classes and whitespace in the tag are ignored.

---

Here's a minimal, runnable example illustrating all of the points raised above:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<p class="y x">A</p>
<p class="x   y">B</p>
<p class="x y z">C</p>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);

  /*.....................*/
  /*...... correct ......*/
  console.log("----- correct output -----");
  const firstText = await page.$eval("p", el => el.textContent);
  console.log(firstText); // => A
  const allText = await page.$$eval("p", els =>
    els.map(e => e.textContent)
  );
  console.log(allText); // => [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]

  const allTextClassy = await page.$$eval(".x.y", els =>
    els.map(e => e.textContent)
  );
  console.log(allTextClassy); // => [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]

  /*.....................*/
  /*..... incorrect .....*/
  console.log("\n---- incorrect output ----");
  const firstWrong = await page.$$eval(
    "p",
    el => el.textContent
  );
  console.log(firstWrong); // undefined

  const allWrong = [];
  try {
    await page.$$eval("p", els => allWrong.push(42)); // throws
  }
  catch (err) {
    // Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: allWrong is not defined
    console.error(err.message);
  }

  const allTextUnclassy = await page.$$eval(
    '[class="x y"]',
    els => els.map(e => e.textContent)
  );
  console.log(allTextUnclassy); // => [] (missing 'A' because of ordering,
  //                                      missing 'B' because of whitespace,
  //                                      missing 'C' because of extra class)
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```